# Queries on the same big data dataset

Tags: bigdata

Lets say I have a very big dataset (billions of records), one that doesnt fit on a single machine and I want to have multiple unknown queries (its a service where a user can choose a certain subset of the dataset and I need to return the max of that subset).

For the computation itself I was thinking about Spark or something similar, problem is Im going to have a lot of IO/network activity since Spark is going to have to keep re-reading the data set from the disk and distributing it to the workers, instead of, for instance, having Spark divide the data among the workers when the cluster goes up and then just ask from each worker to do the work on certain records (by their number, for example).

So, to the big data people here, what do you usually do? Just have Spark redo the read and distribution for every request?
If I want to do what I said above I have no choice but to write something of my own?

Comment: Sounds like you are thinking of MPP machine. Spark is not a database. Anyway, you can cache things but all these are shared resources andcat thevend of a Spark job caches fet released.

Comment: excuse spelling

Comment: What is MPP? I know Spark isnt a database, its going to have to read it from a database/some storage and that is the problem. Yes I can cache things but we are talking about billions of records, I dont think the cache will be very effective, especially if there are no "hot" subsets of the data

Comment: Massively paralle processing. Db in this case. Like db2,nosql

Comment: Cache will spill to disk. At end of job all released. Sounds like you get it so what is the point of asking?

Answer (score 0):

If the queries are known but the subsets unknown, you could precalculate the max (or whatever the operator) for many smaller windows / slices of the data. This gives you a small and easily queried index of sorts, which might allow you to calculate the max for an arbitrary subset. In case a subset does not start and end neatly where your slices do, you just need to process the ‘outermost’ partial slices to get the result.

If the queries are unknown, you might want to consider storing the data in a MPP database or use OLAP cubes (Kylin, Druid?) depending on the specifics; or you could store the data in a columnar format such as Parquet for efficient querying.

Comment: The queries are knows but the amount of subsets are way too big to calculate anything that would help significantly, users choose 2 subsets, first one is a subset of a million entries, the other is of about 3k.
Maybe MPP is the way to go.

Comment: Too many to precalculate? I’ll take that as a challenge - could you give an example?

Comment: Million entries, each has 3k name->number pairs.
Given a subset of the million entries and a subset of the names, you want the average for each name for all the entries in the subset.
So each possible subset (of each possible size) of a million entries is too much to calculate and keep.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a precalculating solution based on the problem description in the OP's comment to my other answer:

> Million entries, each has 3k name->number pairs. Given a subset of the million entries and a subset of the names, you want the average for each name for all the entries in the subset. So each possible subset (of each possible size) of a million entries is too much to calculate and keep.

---

## Precalculation

First, we split the data into smaller 'windows' (shards, pages, partitions).

Let's say each window contains around 10k rows with roughly 20k distinct names and 3k (name,value) pairs in each row (choosing the window size can affect performance, and you might be better off with smaller windows).

Assuming ~24 bytes per name and 2 bytes for the value, each window contains 10k*3k*(24+2 bytes) = 780 MB of data plus some overhead that we can ignore.

For each window, we precalculate the number of occurrences of each name, as well as the sum of the values for that name. With those two values we can calculate the average for a name over any set of windows as:

```
Average for name N = (sum of sums for N)/(sum of counts for N)
```

Here's a small example with much less data:

```
Window 1
{'aaa':20,'abcd':25,'bb':10,'caca':25,'ddddd':50,'bada':30}
{'aaa':12,'abcd':31,'bb':15,'caca':24,'ddddd':48,'bada':43}

Window 2
{'abcd':34,'bb':8,'caca':22,'ddddd':67,'bada':9,'rara':36}
{'aaa':21,'bb':11,'caca':25,'ddddd':56,'bada':17,'rara':22}

Window 3
{'caca':20,'ddddd':66,'bada':23,'rara':29,'tutu':4}
{'aaa':10,'abcd':30,'bb':8,'caca':42,'ddddd':38,'bada':19,'tutu':6}
```

The precalculated Window 1 'index' with sums and counts:

```
{'aaa':[32,2],'abcd':[56,2],'bb':[25,2],'caca':[49,2],'ddddd':[98,2],'bada':[73,2]}
```

This 'index' will contain around 20k distinct names and two values for each name, or 20k*(24+2+2 bytes) = 560 KB of data. That's one thousand times less than the data itself.

---

## Querying

Now let's put this in action: given an input spanning 1 million rows, you'll need to load (1M/10k)=100 indices or 56 MB, which fits easily in memory on a single machine (heck, it would fit in memory on your smartphone).

But since you are aggregating the results, you can do even better; you don't even need to load all of the indices at once, you can load them one at a time, filter and sum the values, and discard the index before loading the next. That way you could do it with just a few megabytes of memory.

More importantly, the calculation should take no more than a few seconds for any set of windows and names. If the names are sorted alphabetically (another worthwhile pre-optimization) you get the best performance, but even with unsorted lists it should run more than fast enough.

### Corner cases

The only thing left to do is handle the case where the input span doesn't line up exactly with the precalculated windows. This requires a little bit of logic for the two 'ends' of the input span, but it can be easily built into your code.

Say each window contains exactly one week of data, from Monday through Sunday, but your input specifies a period starting on a Wednesday. In that case you would have to load the actual raw data from Wednesday through Sunday of the first week (a few hundred megabytes as we noted above) to calculate the (count,sum) tuples for each name first, and then use the indices for the rest of the input span.

This does add some processing time to the calculation, but with an upper bound of 2*780MB it still fits very comfortably on a single machine.

---

At least that's how I would do it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
Its a nice optimization but it assumes there is some sort of pattern to what subset (of the millions entries) the user would ask for, because if he'll ask for X number of each "window" that I have and not full "window"s, this optimization does nothing

Comment: Ah, yes I assumed the input selection was a range from a starting row to an ending row. If the row selection is completely arbitrary then you can’t use my solution.